# On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Tags: git

Загружаю бота на Heroku
пишу

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "My project"
```

и вот тут вылазит ошибка:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Перевод ошибки "На мастере ветки нечего коммитить, рабочее дерево чистое" почитай [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Значит у вас проект пустой, ни одного файла. Пустую папку закоммитить невозможно.